# AngularJS Disable ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In AngularJS, is there any way to make an `ng-click` dependent upon a boolean?

For example, I'd like the following text ("Click") to be clickable, but *only* when some scope property (e.g., `$rootScope.enableClick`) is `true`.

```
<div ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Click</div>
```

Preferably, is there a straightforward way to do this without creating a custom directive?

Comment: You can replace `+1` with scope var `+increment`

Comment: And what would it be when not clickable, disabled, hidden, any other?

Comment: The text should still show when it's not clickable. I know, it makes no sense - but just an example.

Comment: Give the `div` a class name according to the boolean `enableClick` and the style the div with the help of that class name in a way that `pointer-events: none;`. So it will be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the strange and wonderfull [`&&` logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) in the `ng-click` expression:

```
<div ng-click="!stop && (count = count + 1)">Click me</div>
```

## The DEMO

```css
.clickable {
   cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="count=0">
   <div ng-click="!stop && (count = count + 1)" class="clickable" >Click Me</div>
   <div>Count={{count}}</div>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="stop">Stop counting<br>
</body>
```

---

## Update

Or use a <kbd>button</kbd> with the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive:

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-disabled="stop" >Click Me</button>
```

The [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive does not work with `<div>` elements. The `disabled` property is not a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). The `ng-disabled` directive only works with `<input>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements as those elements support the [`disabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled).

## The DEMO

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="count=0">
   <button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-disabled="stop" >Click Me</button>
   <div>Count={{count}}</div>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="stop">Stop counting<br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, I have used the same method as @georgeawg used. The difference is that I have made it as a button format and used `pointer-events: none` so that no click event will be triggered from the `.clickable`

```css
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.clickable:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.test {
  color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="count=0">
  <div>Count={{count}}</div>
   <div ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-class="{'test': stop}" class="clickable">Click Me</div>
   
   <div>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="stop">Stop counting
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" ng-disabled="!enableClick">Click</div>
```

> The ng-disabled directive sets the disabled attribute of a form field
>   (input, select, or textarea).

Comment: Hm, for some reason this seems to work if I change the div to a button - but not when it's a div.

Comment: The `ng-disabled` directive does not work with `<div>` elements. The `disabled` property is not a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). The `ng-disabled` directive only works with `<input>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements as those elements support the [`disabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled).