# how to add ng-dbclick if condition is verified angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to inject `ng-dbclick` if just a condition is `true` :

```
<li ng-if="condition ? ng-dblclick='event()':nothing">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Another solution could be to check the condition insde the onclick call. Something like <li ngdblclick='event(condition)'></li> or just implement the if inside the event method event(){if(condition){...}}

Comment: ok thanks but i will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Disable ngClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845858/angularjs-disable-ngclick/51846416#51846416)

Comment: @LeonardoNeninger You should add that as an answer. Then you will get points when people upvote it. I like solutions that remove the clutter from the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this :

```
<li ng-dblclick="condition && event()">...</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create two `li`'s

```
<li ng-if="condition" ng-dblclick="event()">
  <your-component />
</li>
<li ng-if="!condition">
  <your-component />
</li>
```

Otherwise you'll need to compile the template and do it on the javascript and not on the template. 
You can take a look at the following:
[Dynamically Import Component From Variable (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964879/dynamically-import-component-from-variable-angularjs/46976122#46976122)

Comment: Seems like alot of overhead to disable a double-click handler. This code adds two watchers and destroys and un-destroys a component. Also the `ng-if` directive adds a child scope. It's like tearing out a light fixture and replacing it when you want light in a room. Simply add an on-off switch.

Comment: I could understand and agree with everything except for `Simply add an on-off switch`. What do you mean with that?
As a suggestion to the author of the question I would say that https://stackoverflow.com/a/51880094/3483221 is the one that is way more performative